# C++ Refactoring Precompiled Header

Tags: c++, refactoring, precompiled-headers

Unfortunately on a project here at work, someone had the great idea to put every header every single file from pretty big project into the precompiled header. This means any change to any header in the project has to recompile the entire project, and all cpp files taking way too long.

Is there any decent C++ refactoring tool which could automatically put the needed includes in the appropriate cpp files? I really don't want to do this manually with hundreds of different files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very few decent C++ refactoring tools because parsing C++ code is hard (and therefore also slow).  You'll probably have to write such a tool yourself, possibly with some assistance from [GCC-XML](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html).